# Open source onboard file sync usb program. Need to allow user input paths with config.ini, but issues

Tags: python

[screen snip of config.ini file bc escape chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jWwI.png)
conversion function because config reads in as a string

```
def convert(in_str):
result = []
current_tuple = []
for token in in_str.split(","):
    path = (token.replace("(","").replace(")", ""))
    current_tuple.append(path)
    if ")" in token:
       result.append(tuple(current_tuple))
       current_tuple = []
return result
```

I want it to be scalable, but the type of the path doesn't get accepted into python's glob.glob()

Leaving it as string returns []
Casting to Path gives "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" with a WindowsPath argument

I've tried all 4 combos of: 1/2 backslashes in config paths and y/n cast to Path in convert()

It worked fine when hardcoded with 2 backslashes, but I'm exporting it to an exe with auto-py-to-exe for the ability to autorun on insert, thus the config file.
Any additional ideas would be appreciated as well

python version 3.7.4